# Parallax stop background image pos change if scroll exceeds bg image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I have multiple sections showing different backgrounds, each section has a basic parallax background image. As the backgrounds vary in height, I cannot seem to work out how to stop the background image position once the image bottom is reached.

Background position change begins if the section `offset().top` is equal to or greater than `$(window).scrollTop()`.

It would seem that the `btmOffset` is incorrect but I can't see why.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**Live example**
http://demo.dwweb.co.uk

**What I have so far**

```
$window = $(window);
var winWid = $window.width();
$('.portfolioSection').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this);
        var speed = 2.4;
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image').replace('url("','').replace('")','');
        var tmpImg = new Image();
        tmpImg.src = bg;
        var orgW = tmpImg.width;
        var orgH = tmpImg.height; 
        var imgResizedRatio = winWid/orgW;
        var resizedH = orgH * imgResizedRatio;
        var btmOffset =  (resizedH - $(this).height()) + $bgobj.offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > $bgobj.offset().top && $(window).scrollTop() < btmOffset){
                var yPos = -(($window.scrollTop()-$bgobj.offset().top) / speed); 
                var coords = '0 '+ yPos + 'px';
                $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
            } else if($(window).scrollTop() < $bgobj.offset().top) {
                $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: '0 0' });
            } else {
                $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: '0 '+resizedH+'px' });
            }
        }); 

    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a working example.

Comment: Sorry, that would definitely have helped! http://demo.dwweb.co.uk

Comment: Are these images of these websites the parallax background images?

Comment: @Wumm - Yes, the issue is that the height of each screengrab varies.

Comment: Somehow I'm unable to see any parallax in work at all on that link. Chrome 32.

Comment: Ok, for some reason it doesn't want to work in Chrome. Works OK in Firefox. My main site is http://dwhite.me, and confirm working in Chrome 33.x. I think it's an issue with this (the Q) code as the demo.dwweb.co.uk site contains the above script, the live dwhite.me site has a more basic version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orgH` and `orgW` will be 0 on execution, since you are creating a new Image  **asynchronously**, while executing your code **synchronously**:

```
var tmpImg = new Image();
tmpImg.src = bg;
//...
```

This means, you would have to use the `onload` event (and maybe cover the `onerror` event too), like this:

```
tmpImg.onload = function(ev) {
    var orgW = tmpImg.width;
    var orgH = tmpImg.height; 
    //and the rest of your code...
}
```

This is very inefficient, since you are loading all these (big) images again.
I would add data-attributes to each `.portfolioSection`, like `data-bgmaxscroll="1000"` (which is the height of the image).

This would be a bit more hardcoded, but i think it's the easiest and the most performant way.

Comment: Thanks @bbuecherl, That got me on the right path. Totally slipped my mind that you can use a data attr to set anything.